# I am trying to tail a log file and check for server up condition, once the string matches, it should return the same O/P in the variable.

Tags: bash

The problem is that tail -f doesn't exits by itself and my script stalls.

I am using sleep 15 because after triggering the shutdown command string 'org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol' appears after 15 sec in logs. In this way tail -100 works and gives the desired result.

Below is the snippet of code which I have written and its working fine, but I want to check it dynamically by tail -f. Please guide me how can I do it by tail -f and exiting the tail by some way.

```
ALFRESCO_LOGS="$CATALINA_BASE/logs"

    printf "Stopping alfresco instance.\n\n"

    $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh &> /dev/null
    sleep 15
    CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS=$(tail -100 $ALFRESCO_LOGS/catalina.out | grep --line-buffered 'org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol' | awk 'NR==1{print $NF}')
     echo "$CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS"

    if [[ "$CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS" == "stop" ]];
    then
            echo "Alfresco instance has been stopped."
    fi
```

Comment: Do you want the script to block until `stop` is seen?

Comment: yes , but the stop should be the latest one, as the logs may contain multiple stop msgs.

Comment: "Latest one" isn't defined with `tail -f`, because you never know if another one might be coming.

Comment: usually tail -f will contain only one stop message, that's what I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with `tail -f` receiving `SIGPIPE`, this is a straightforward way:

```
while read CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS; do
    echo "$CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS"

    if [[ "$CHECK_ALFRESCO_LOGS" == "stop" ]]; then
        echo "Alfresco instance has been stopped."
        break
    fi
done < <( tail -f $ALFRESCO_LOGS/catalina.out | awk '/org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol/{print $NF}')
```

When the condition matches, the while loop ends. That closes the input redirection, and thus the `tail` process receives `SIGPIPE`, which closes it.

Comment: ..it went into infinite loop as tail -f never exited.

Comment: But, did you get that print for `"instance has been stopped"`?

Comment: Does the `awk` need an `exit`?

Comment: yeah , that may work..can you tell me the syntax pls.

Comment: Instead of `{print $NF}` use `{print $NF; exit}`.  In fact I'm not even sure what good the `print $NF` is so try just `{exit}`.

Comment: @anishsane adding a `-n0` to the `tail` command seems like it would it implement the "match the latest one" condition that the OP had.